# How to trigger when action in separate thread is complete?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, cursor, controls

**EDIT2: This is not simply a cross-thread issue. I can update controls based on the above link, but it's just not working for Cursor or toolStrip. Not working means not working. I receive the usual error message, that the control is created in another thread so it can't be modified. Invoke is not an option for toolStrip.**

On a button click I initiate some actions in a separate thread. It's necessary as it may take a while and my form usually gets frozen. My issue is that I have to modify a couple of controls, and set them back at the end, which I can't do from the worker thread. How to solve this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Working...";
    Thread thread = new Thread(query);
    thread.Start();
}
private void query()
{
    //actions
    //here I need to set the cursor back to default
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default; //but this is obviously not working
    //and I have to set the label text to be "done"
    //which is not working as well as invoke is not an option for toolStrips
}
```

So I need some solution to do the above. Maybe some backgroundworker to "keep an eye" on the query() thread and action once it's done?

**EDIT3: I can modify any attribute of any control with the below piece of code, except for toolStrip:**

```
delegate void SetControlValueCallback(Control oControl, string propName, object propValue);
    private void SetControlPropertyValue(Control oControl, string propName, object propValue)
    {
        if (oControl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetControlValueCallback d = new SetControlValueCallback(SetControlPropertyValue);
            oControl.Invoke(d, new object[] { oControl, propName, propValue });
        }
        else
        {
            Type t = oControl.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
            {
                if (p.Name.ToUpper() == propName.ToUpper())
                {
                    p.SetValue(oControl, propValue, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION:** thank you Marc Gravell for the idea

```
private void query()
{
    //actions
    Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "done";
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you Marc Gravell for the idea

```
private void query()
{
    //actions
    Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "done";
    }));
}
```